# UIMenu title and icon appears backwards

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, uikit, uimenu

I have issue with UIMenu in IOS.
The menu appears in reverse, as the icon and title backwards
[image]

and here is my code

```
- (UIContextMenuConfiguration*) tableView : (UITableView*)tableView contextMenuConfigurationForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath point:(CGPoint)point {

UIContextMenuConfiguration* config = [UIContextMenuConfiguration configurationWithIdentifier:@"ayah-controls"
                                                                             previewProvider:nil
                                                                              actionProvider:^UIMenu* _Nullable(NSArray<UIMenuElement*>* _Nonnull suggestedActions) {

    NSMutableArray* actions = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [actions addObject:[UIAction actionWithTitle:@"Copy"  image:[UIImage systemImageNamed:@"doc.on.doc.fill"] identifier:nil handler:^(__kindof UIAction* _Nonnull action) {

    }]];
    [actions addObject:[UIAction actionWithTitle:@"مشاركة الاية" image:[UIImage systemImageNamed:@"square.and.arrow.up.fill"] identifier:nil handler:^(__kindof UIAction* _Nonnull action) {

    }]];
    
    [actions addObject:[UIAction actionWithTitle:@"حفظ في المفضلة" image:[UIImage systemImageNamed:@"bookmark.fill"] identifier:nil handler:^(__kindof UIAction* _Nonnull action) {

    }]];
    
    [actions addObject:[UIAction actionWithTitle:@"إستمع للآية" image:[UIImage systemImageNamed:@"play.fill"] identifier:nil handler:^(__kindof UIAction* _Nonnull action) {

    }]];

    UIMenu* menu = [UIMenu menuWithChildren:actions];
    return menu;
}];

return config;
```

}

Comment: You are localized for a RTL language.

Comment: SF Symbols are localized too

Comment: My app default language is arabic everything works fine when i change app localization to en

Comment: @AliAl-Jiachi I'm seeing the same thing - wondering if you ever solved this, and if so, how? Thanks!

Comment: I think the answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74023736/6449292