# Mirrored actions on UIActivityViewController, swift, with persian language (iOS 15.4)

Tags: swift, xcode, uiactivityviewcontroller, farsi

[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFpsE.png)

As you can see my actions are mirrored while I set my application language to persian.
It just happening on iOS 15.4 older versions are works fine
my main text share is in persion and it's not mirrored, just my actions are mirrored.
this is my code

```
        let textShare = [ text ]
        let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: textShare , applicationActivities: nil)
        activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
        self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I tired to re mirror the view but my share text is mirrored too:

```
activityViewController.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(a: -1, b: 0, c: 0, d: 1, tx: 0, ty: 0)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

i solve this issue by adding english language to project localization and force app to use my language into app delegate file without mirror any view
[image]
best regards

Answer (score 1):

1- Right click on your project ".xcodeproj" file and choose "Show Package Contents"

2- Right click on the "project.pbxproj" open it with "TextEdit".

3- Find the "developmentRegion" key and set it to "en".
[image]

Done.

Comment: Ok after i upvote your answer i faced another issue, if i run app from debug it works fine but if i launch it not from debug the app run LTR not RTL.

Comment: Check the run options, This is the right way to do it. the base app must be English and LTR and when you run the app, based on the device language, it should switch to RTL automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, it's about **DevelopmentRegion**. I had added the development region in the project info.plist file and easily solve this issue by removing it.

Remove `Development localization` from the info.plist if you open it as `Property List`.

[image: Property List]

*or*

Remove `CFBundleDevelopmentRegion` from the info.plist if you open it as `Source Code`.

[image: Source Code]